# Does Mantle require a Model to be fully specified?

Tags: ios, json, mapping

I am consuming JSON that is constantly evolving. I started writing code to consume the JSON using Mantle lately.  It seemed like a very good choice for what I want to do.  However, it seems that if the JSON being consumed has properties that do not exist in the model, the JSON transformation fails.  I'm using the `[MTLJSONAdapter modelOfClass:fromJSONDictionary:error:];` call to map the JSON.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

Upon closer inspection of the code, Mantle does require that all json properties map to something in the model.  Otherwise, what will happen is an exception will be thrown for that property.

inside of `MTLValidateAndSetValue` of MTLModel, it doesn't check for the existence of the property before it sets it.

```
@try {
    if (![obj validateValue:&validatedValue forKey:key error:error]) return NO;

    if (forceUpdate || value != validatedValue) {
        [obj setValue:validatedValue forKey:key];
    }

    return YES;
} @catch (NSException *ex) {
    NSLog(@"*** Caught exception setting key \"%@\" : %@", key, ex);

    // Fail fast in Debug builds.
    #if DEBUG
    @throw ex;
    #else
    if (error != NULL) {
        *error = [NSError mtl_modelErrorWithException:ex];
    }

    return NO;
    #endif
}
```

This is problematic if the JSON you are consuming isn't guaranteed to match your model.
I ended up doing  a custom JSON representation for my work having the constructor build the object based on the incoming JSON rather than against the model. It will first iterate over the json properties and tries to map them directly to the model properties using implicit mapping.  If there are any properties that require special handling, it is up to the subclass to override the init call and apply the transformation manually.